# xcode "build and analyze" does not work properly with properties

Tags: xcode

This has been bugging me for quite some time.

lets say you've got a property

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *test;
```

Within your implementation you use:

```
self.test = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

(only an example).

The result is, that the newly allocated NSString object has a Retain-Count of 2.
Releasing the Object in the dealloc method only reduces the count to 1 resulting in memory leaks.

Is there a way for "Build and Analyze" to recognize these leaks? oO

Answer (score 3):

[File a bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=clang).  This, IMO, is definitely something the analyzer should catch.

Answer (score -1):

> Within your implementation you use...

There is your problem, actually:

```
 self.test = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

Just never do that, as it's plain wrong. Say the property was copy instead of retain: you would not have a pointer to that object anymore, buy still own it - a memory leak right there and no way to recover (who would you send the release message?).

Comment: @w.m of course it's wrong.  @Infinite's point is that the static analyzer should also know that it's wrong and throw up an error.

Comment: Sure, it would be nice if the Analyzer could notice the problem there. But Infinite wrote it was bugging him/her for "quite some time", so I suggested there might be an underlying coding style problem, which can't really be fixed by an Analyzer message.

Comment: actually no... (although I had at the beginning) a simple autorelease behind the init would be enough to solve the problem. It's really about the analyzer part.

Comment: Yes, agreed. And exactly what the Analyzer (if fixed some time in the future) could tell you here - that a simple autorelease at the end will plug this memory leak. And this is, in my mind, something you should still not do, because it obfuscates the whole object ownership idea. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: Do you even use build and analyze? oO Xcode has a beautiful way to show you when an object has been initialized, when its reference count has been incremented and when its been released. It still doesn't tell you what to do and a message like "Potential leak of an object allocated on line xyz". The Problem here is the context... Checking a function is a whole nother deal than checking the whole possible lifetime of an object of a class.

Comment: Still... I would like to know why you think it would obfuscate the object ownership idea. Not every class has convenience methods which already return autoreleased objects.

Comment: Interesting. So what I didn't realize earlier was that the Analyzer completely ignores the created object if you pass it in a method call to self; I thought the problem lied with assigning the object to a local property or something. Thanks for enlightening me, I can see now that that is a real issue.

Comment: Normally (in the code I work with), when you init/copy/take ownership of an object, you put that into a pointer local to the function or {}-block you're in right now. In that case it would be NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init]; When looking through the code with an eye on memory management, this myString is the object one now owns, and consequently has to get rid of some time. That scheme breaks with your line where you lose every reference to the object, you don't have a "grip" on the object you own.

Comment: I wouldn't do it like that and go back to the old scheme instead where I assign the object to a local pointer, just because I think otherwise I might be introducing unnecessary bugs. I guess it's a matter of personal taste, and if you're happy with just making sure that every creation has an autorelease on the same line, that might work just fine for you.

Comment: interesting... in most of my code I work exactly as you do, but it's because I don't trust autorelease. If there was a problem with the memory management I wouldnt get errors the moment they are created. But sometimes I prefer cleaner code instead.